# Font Awesome + Bootstrap Tool Bar Animation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a 360 tour via Kolor Panotour Pro (which uses an xml based code "krpano").

I'm using a bootstrap html template build when I export my project so it has nice looking ui buttons.

The default Bootstrap template using Glyphicons for the toolbar that are incompatible with IE.

I've since switched to Font Awesome and it is now showing perfectly fine, except for one issue.

Here is an image of the toolbar below...
[image]

When you hit this toggle for Thumbnails, a row of thumbnails pops up from the bottom. Pic below.
[image]

The issue, is that the black toolbar is supposed to animate up and out of the way just above the row of thumbs.

The issue doesn't happen when the original template using the glyphicons is present. But as soon as I change the thumbs toggle button to the Font Awesome fa-eye, the toolbar doesn't move. I know I'm missing some action call of some sort but I've searched everywhere and I can't find it.

Here's some code of what I'm looking at...

The eye button

```
<button     type="button"
                                class="btn btn-default btn-lg toggle-thumbnails"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                title="Toggle thumbnails">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye" style="color: white;"></i>
                    </button>
```

Custom function (that maybe has to do with animating it?). I've since switched out the info with fa-eye, as it was previously the old glyphicon before.

```
//Show Hide Thumbnails
        var toggleThumbnails = function(){
            jQuery('#thumbnailsDIV').toggle("slow", function() {
                if(jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails span").hasClass('fa-eye')) {
                    jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails span").removeClass('fa-eye').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
                    jQuery('#toolbar').animate({bottom:'175px'});
                    jQuery('.toggle-thumbnails span').css({color: fg2xLighter});
                }else{
                    jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails span").removeClass('fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye');
                    jQuery('#toolbar').animate({bottom:'50px'});
                    jQuery('.toggle-thumbnails span').css({color: '#{{project.description.fgcolor}}'});
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: In any case, instead of `.removeClass('fa-eye').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash')` use `.toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash')`

Comment: Thanks! That'll definitely clean it up a bit. That was the default in the template.

Comment: Hopefully I can figure out the toolbar issue!  :S

Comment: I spotted it so I hope you don't take too long before checking back here

Comment: Given URL in the edit works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: https://codyhouse.co/demo/stretchy-navigation/edit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, it would seem that the tag will have been `<span>` when you used Glyphicons, and now it's `<i>` as per FontAwesome's instructions.

`<i class="fa fa-eye" style="color: white;"></i>`

This selector, seeking `<span>` finds nothing

`jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails span")`

Use this

`if(jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails i").hasClass('fa-eye')) {`

and you also need to change the other `span`s to `i`s

```
var toggleThumbnails = function(){
    jQuery('#thumbnailsDIV').toggle("slow", function() {
        if(jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails i").hasClass('fa-eye')) {
            jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails i").removeClass('fa-eye').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
            jQuery('#toolbar').animate({bottom:'175px'});
            jQuery('.toggle-thumbnails i').css({color: fg2xLighter});
        }else{
            jQuery(".toggle-thumbnails i").removeClass('fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye');
            jQuery('#toolbar').animate({bottom:'50px'});
            jQuery('.toggle-thumbnails i').css({color: '#{{project.description.fgcolor}}'});
        }
    });
};
```

But I'd reduce DOM searches and tidy it up to this:

```
var toggleThumbnails = function(){
    jQuery('#thumbnailsDIV').toggle("slow", function() {

        var $icon = jQuery('.toggle-thumbnails i'); // find once and re-use 
        var color; // alter this and make one call to update $icon later
        var bottom; // to remove duplicate code

        if ($icon.hasClass('fa-eye')) {
            bottom = 175;
            color = fg2xLighter;
        }else{
            bottom = 50;
            color = '#{{project.description.fgcolor}}';
        }

        // update the icon and toolbar
        jQuery('#toolbar').animate({bottom: bottom}); // doesn't need 'px'
        $icon.toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash').css({color: color});
    });
};
```

Comment: Wow that definitely cleaned up that bit there didn't it. It definitely helped, although the toolbar issue is still there hmm... the eye icon doesn't toggle between eye and eye-slash either (it didn't before the <i> change either)... I'll post the code in entirety. (I'll edit my post.) Thanks again for that!

Comment: Hey man!!! Just in case... I took the old DOM that wasn't as tidy, and changed the 'span' stuff, and it WORKS. Not sure what the difference is between the old and the shorter version (I'm not THAT familiar with code to know), but in any case, you definitely helped me solved the problem. YOU ARE THE MAN/WOMAN!! :)

Comment: The old version, with all `span`s swapped with `i`s should have worked also.

Comment: No yeah thats what I mean. The original jQuery with the extra .removeClass and .toggleClass in it worked with the 'i's, but for some reason the reduced code didn't work! No idea!